# I was trying to access the symbol (bomb) from library on clicking a button in AS3. I keep getting various errors like 1065 or 1007

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
stop();
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

button1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, s);
function s(event:TouchEvent)
{
    for (var counter = 0; counter<1; counter++)
    {
      //create new bombs

        var bomb = new Bomb;

      //add it to the stage
        addChildAt(bomb,1);
        bomb.x = ball.x;
        bomb.y = ball.y;`enter code here`


        ball.gotoAndPlay(2);

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't bother telling what the errors says so I guess we have to look them up? Voted down as you don't make much effort to provide info.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
addChildAt(bomb,1);
```

can produce an error since it refers to a display list index that might not be available. If no objects are on the display list only the index 0 is available on the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

go to your library -> right click on the symbol -> properties -> check the Export For ActionScript.
then copy the the name that you have enterd in **Class** field.
then hit F9 and add it like this:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

var sp:Sprite = new Symbol1;
addChild(sp);
```